# Trying to compare objects to determine change and update scope based on that

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Sorry I'm not sure how to ask this question but the code is pretty straight forward I think. I want to check if the data being returned from the DB has changed and if so update the scope. However when I do the compare it always comes back as different and does the update:

```
$scope.tickets = Ticket.tickets.query();

updateTickets = $interval(function(){
 var deferred = $q.defer();
 $scope.curTickets = $scope.tickets;
 deferred.resolve(Ticket.tickets.query());
 var promise = deferred.promise;

 promise.then(function(newTickets){
  $scope.newTickets = newTickets;
  if($scope.curTickets != $scope.newTickets){
    $scope.tickets = $scope.newTickets;
    console.log('newtickets!');
  } else {
    console.log('no newtickets');
  }
 });

},90000);
```

Comment: How do I see what php file is returning you buddy ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/201471/3878940, there is no definite way of comparing the equality of 2 objects in JavaScript. So, you may need to look for an alternative approach to recursively compare the values of the response object by writing a custom method.

Comment: Thanks, I found the .equals works but I had to change the way I was returning the object and use a function to handle the returned data:

`Ticket.tickets.query({},function(data){

      $scope.newTickets = data;`

etc etc.